# Why string.replace() not working for string which contains parentheses?

Tags: javascript, regex

Below is the function which add html bold tag to sub-string we passed.

```js
function boldString(str, find) {
    var re = new RegExp(find, 'g');
    return str.replace(re, '<b>' + find + '</b>');
}  

console.log(boldString("this is for testing purpose","testing"));
console.log(boldString("testing with (parentheses)","(parentheses)"));
```

Why in second case output is not as expected?

Comment: backslash needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escape string for use in Javascript regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446170/escape-string-for-use-in-javascript-regex)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parentheses are a reserved symbol in regular expressions.  You would bump into the same problem with e.g. `.`, `+`, `*`, `[]` etc.

You'll want to [add escape characters to the text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446170/escape-string-for-use-in-javascript-regex) before constructing a regexp out of it. (Also, it's better to use `.replace()`s function-accepting form and use the actual match string.)

```
function escapeRegExp(str) {
  return str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
}

function boldString(str, find) {
    var re = new RegExp(escapeRegExp(find), 'g');
    return str.replace(re, function (m) {
      return '<b>' + m + '</b>';
    });
}
```

Comment: `escapeRegExp(find)` can be simplified to `find.replace(/\W/g, "\\$&")`.

Comment: `/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/` can be simplified to `/[-\[\]/{}()*+?.\\^$|]/`.

Comment: Sure. The function is simply the accepted answer in the question I linked :)

Answer (score 1):

Because `(` and `)` (and several other characters) have special meaning in regular expressions, and you haven't escaped them. You'd need to pass in `"\\(parentheses\\)"`: The first backslash escapes the second in the string literal so that the string actually contains a backslash; that backslash in the string escapes the `(` and `)`.

Example:

```js
function boldString(str, find) {
    var re = new RegExp(find, 'g');
    return str.replace(re, '<b>' + find + '</b>');
}  

console.log(boldString("this is for testing purpose","testing"));
console.log(boldString("testing with (parentheses)","\\(parentheses\\)"));
```

Of course, without changing your `boldString`'s inputs, that's going to include the backslashes in the output as well. As [melpomene](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1848654/melpomene) pointed out in a comment, you can fix that by using `$&` as the replacement, which will be the text matched by the exppression:

```js
function boldString(str, find) {
    var re = new RegExp(find, 'g');
    return str.replace(re, '<b>$&</b>');
}  

console.log(boldString("this is for testing purpose","testing"));
console.log(boldString("testing with (parentheses)","\\(parentheses\\)"));
```

If you're accepting end-user input, [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript) have functions you can use to add any necessary escapes. For instance, using the one from the [currently-accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3561711/157247):

```js
RegExp.escape= function(s) {
    return s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
};

function boldString(str, find) {
    var re = new RegExp(RegExp.escape(find), 'g');
    return str.replace(re, '<b>' + find + '</b>');
}  

console.log(boldString("this is for testing purpose","testing"));
console.log(boldString("testing with (parentheses)","(parentheses)"));
```